# Как узнать кодировку сайта?

Tags: php, html, кодировка

При парсинге [сайта](http://www.travel.ru/news/) в мою базу данных и затем на сайтик выдается "каша".

Код ниже не работает, так как первоначальная кодировка неизвестна.

```php
iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$name)
```

Как определить, какая кодировка установлена [на сайте](http://www.travel.ru/news/)?

P.S. Мета-тегов там нет.

Comment: В 2023 году вопрос для указанного сайта неактуален, кодировка указана в мета-теге: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 3):

Вот большая [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107945/) на эту тему.

Однозначно могу сказать одно - если хотите качественно, то самый надежный способ - это иметь таблицу соответствий сайт-кодировка для тех, которые не определяются правильно. А все остальные по meta тегам и http заголовкам.

Но помните, что есть сайты, у которых только подбором и визуальным контролем можно узнать кодировку. А есть ещё сайты, на которых часть страницы в одной, а часть - в другой:).

Comment: Вот насчет разных страниц в разной кодировке правильно подмечено.

Хотя для предложенного в вопросе сайта FF определил, что там cp1251. Почему у TC каша после iconv() ? Видимо надо конкретней разбираться.

Comment: Короче, Шерлок Холмс, Пляшущие Человечки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Может быть статистическую формулу подобрать, выбирать кодировку в
       зависимости от среднего значения байт, байты меньше 128 не учитывать.
2. Перебирая разные кодировки, применяем aspell и минимизируем количество нераспознанных слов.

Comment: Ещё варианты есть?=))))

Comment: Ну ещё HTTP заголовки но в них с данного сайта я тоже не обнаружил информации о кодировке.

Comment: Добавил ещё вариант.

Comment: UTF-8 определить очень просто. По первым битам в нескольких байтах. См. [например здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: Но бывает utf-8 и без них...

Comment: @KoVadim, Не понял. 

UTF-8 (способ кодирования UCS (Unicode) 8-ми битными байтами) - без чего бывает ?

Вы видимо имеете в виду случай, когда весь текст ASCII ?

Но в ответе @sercxjo ясно предложено анализировать **не ASCII** (код > 127) байты.

@sercxo, а слова какого языка Вы предлагаете распознавать ?

Comment: @avp, а всех для каких есть словарь, пусть выделят для этого кластер машин :)
за одно и язык сайта узнаем

Comment: @avp О [BOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOM) читали?